# Cannot import IQKeyboardManager in Objective-C project

Tags: objective-c, iqkeyboardmanager

I installed, IQKeyboardManager with pod. using this line:

```
pod 'IQKeyboardManager'
```

Then I wanted to import it in a view controller:
In view controller .m file (I tested both of import lines):

```
1. #import "IQKeyboardManager.h" ----> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

2. @import IQKeyboardManager; ----> Module 'IQKeyboardManager' not found
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to import like this

```
#import <IQKeyboardManager/IQKeyboardManager.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

**IQKeyboardManager (Objective-C)**:- Just drag and drop IQKeyBoardManager directory from demo project to your project. That's it.

it does not require any additional setups in Objective c.

Just Drag and drop.

if you want call any method of IQKeyboardManager then direct call static methods.

[IQKeyboardManager methodName];